# Database class with filters

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm building my own CMS and I used my own Database class for it.
In some frameworks there is a way to do a function on another function

```
$firstValues = $this-db->query('your query')->first();
```

What do I kind of class do I need for the **->first()**.
Is there a way in php to do this? Do I need to use an Abstract class? Does anybody has an example?

If you need any more information, please ask me!
Thanks for helping!

Tom

Comment: You are showing us the "no coding attempt" version of your question.  We prefer to see your "attempted version".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I kind of class do I need for the ->first().

Most frameworks provide a "Query Builder" class to generate and execute SQL statements without writing SQL manually.

> Is there a way in php to do this?

Yes, just pick a query builder:

- https://github.com/cakephp/database
- https://github.com/illuminate/database

> Do I need to use an Abstract class?

No

> Does anybody has an example?

Illuminate Database (Laravel):

```
$userRow = Capsule::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->get();
```

CakePHP:

```php
$userRow = $connection->newQuery()
    ->from('users')
    ->select('*')
    ->where(['votes >' => 20])
    ->execute()
    ->fetch('assoc');
```

Under the hood the `first()` method just fetches the first row.

PDO example:

```php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE votes > :votes LIMIT 1");
$statement->execute(['votes' => 20]);
$userRow = $statement->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass $this between methods.
Here's some example:

```
Class Db {

   private $_query_result;

   public function query($query_string = '')
   {
         // make your query or smth


         // save for example array of results
         $this->_query_result = $your_query_result;
         return $this;
   }

   public function first() 
   {
         return array_shift($this->_query_result);
   }
}
```